# Dynamic content in Firefox OS App

Tags: javascript, dom, dynamic, innerhtml, firefox-os

I have created a Firefox OS app. When I click on the title, it loads some web content, modifies it and shows it by using `div.innerHtml`. This works.

The dynamic content includes some different paragraphs `<p>XXX</p>`. Every paragraph has its own id "text0", "text1" and so on.

When the user clicks on a paragraph, a JavaScript function should be called.

I have googled various websites and tried different ways to add the onclick-Eventhandler to the dynamic content, but none of these seems to work.

Could you have a look at my code?

I have marked the place, where I want to add the event handler with "====>>>>" in the `content.js` extract.

index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
   <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico"/>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/icons.css"/>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/principal.css"/>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/header.css"/>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/toolbar.css"/>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/sidebar.css"/>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/menuaction.css"/>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/menulist.css"/>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/pagebody.css"/>
   <title>FxOS Stub</title>
</head>
<body>
XXX

      <div id="page0" class="pagebody" aria-owns="tb0" aria-expanded="true">
         <!-- Junkyard, only for the sake of the example - NOT for real use -->
         <div id="mainpage" style="margin:0.5rem 1rem 0.5rem 1rem">
         <h2>FxOsStub revisited.</h2>
         <p>This is the first page body (aka page 0, usually your splash screen.)
         <br/>Activate the others by pressing the toolbar's items.</p>
         </div>
         <!-- End of Junkyard - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
      </div>

XXX
      <footer><button>Cancel</button></footer>
   </section>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/temporary.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/dispatcher.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/install.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/toolbar.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/sidebar.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/menuaction.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/menulist.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/pagebody.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/content.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

content.js:

```js
var id_link;//

window.addEventListener(
   "load",
   function() {
            document.getElementById('headline').onclick=LoadContent;
            //document.getElementById('mainpage').onclick=CallPage;
            id_link =  new Object();
   }
);

function CallPage() {
    var display = document.getElementById('mainpage');
    display.innerHTML = "";
}

function LoadContent() {
    // Cross domain XHR
   var display = document.getElementById('mainpage');

   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest({mozSystem: true});
   xhr.mozSystem = true;
   xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xhr.status === 200 && xhr.readyState === 4) 
      {
         //crossDomainXHRDisplay.innerHTML = "<h4>Result from Cross-domain XHR</h4>" + xhr.response;
         //crossDomainXHRDisplay.style.display = "block";
         var iEnd = 0;
         var text = xhr.response;
         var output = "";

         // Clear all Returns
         text = text.replace(/\n/g, "");
         text = text.replace(/\r/g, "");
         //text = text.replace(/<img.*\/>/g, "image");

         // Set HTML header
         output = "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\"\n";
         output = output + "\"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd\">";
         output = output + "<html>\n";
         output = output + "<head>\n";
         output = output + "<title>Spiegel online</title>";
         output = output + "</head>\n";
         output = output + "<body>\n";

         var cnt_it = 0;
         var text_upper = text;
         // Search for headlines
         while(iEnd == 0)
         {
            var match = text.match(/\<h2\sclass\=\"article\-title\">(.+?)<\/h2>(.*)/);

            if(match != null)
            {
               if (match.length > 0)
               {
                  var titel=match[1];
                  var link_src = titel.match(/<a href=\"(.+?)\"\stitle=\"(.+?)".+?>/);
                  id_link[cnt_it]=link_src[1];
                  titel = titel.replace(/<a href=\"(.+?)\"\stitle=\"(.+?)".+?>/,"<h2>$2</h2>");

                  output = output + "<p id=\"text"+cnt_it+"\">" + titel;//match[1];
                  cnt_it++;
                  text = match[2];

                  // Search for article intro
                  var match_intro = text.match(/(.+?)\<h2\sclass\=\"article\-title\">/);
                  if(match_intro != null)
                  {
                     if (match_intro.length > 0)
                     {
                        var search_intro = match_intro[1];
                        var intro = search_intro.match(/<p\sclass\=\"article\-intro clearfix\">(.+?)<\/p.*/);
                        if(intro != null)
                        {
                           if (intro.length > 0)
                           {
                              output = output + intro[1];
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
                  output = output + "</p>\n";
                  iEnd = 1;
               }
            }
            else
            {
               iEnd = 1;
            }
         }
         iEnd = 0;
         var text_test = xhr.response;
         text_test = text_test.match(/.+?<div\sclass=\"auto-width\snav-channel-sub\">(.*)/);
         var text_lower = xhr.response;//text_test[0];
         text_lower = text_lower.replace(/\n/g, "");
         text_lower = text_lower.replace(/\r/g, "");
         text_lower = text_lower.replace(/<img.+?>/g, "");
         while(iEnd == 0)
         {
            var text_lower = text_lower.match(/<ul\sclass\=\"article\-list\">(.+?)<\/ul>(.*)/);
            if(text_lower != null)
            {
               if (text_lower.length > 0)
               {
                  var title = text_lower[1];
                  var link_src = title.match(/<a href=\"(.+?)\" .*<\/a>/);
                  if (link_src != null)
                  {
                     id_link[cnt_it]=link_src[1];
                     title = title.replace(/<a href=\"(.+?)\" title=\"(.+?)\".*>.*<\/a>/, "$2");//" - "+id_link[cnt_it]);
                     //output = output + "<p id=\"text"+cnt_it+"\"><ul class=\"article-list\">" + text_lower[1] + "</ul></p>\n";
                     output = output + "<p onClick=\"CallPage()\" id=\"text"+cnt_it+"\">" + title + "</p>\n";
                     cnt_it++;
                  }
                  text_lower = text_lower[2];
                  iEnd = 1;
               }
               else
               {
                  iEnd = 1;
               }
            }
            else
            {
               iEnd = 1;
            }
         }
         output = output + "</body>\n";
         output = output.replace(/\n/g, "");
         output = output.replace(/\r/g, "");  

====>>> How to add a WORKING event handler to the different paragraphs, which have the id text0, text1 and so on...


         display.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', output);
         //display.innerHTML = output;
         display.style.display = "block";

         //var ObjectUse=display.getElementById("text0");
         //ObjectUse.addEventListener("click", function (event) { alert('Hallo'); CallPage(); }, false);
         //ObjectUse.onclick="alert('Hallo')";//document.CallPage;**

         //var cnt_again = 0;
         //for(cnt_again=0; cnt_again<cnt_it; cnt_again++)
         //{
//            document.getElementById('text'+cnt_again).onclick=CallPage;
//         }
         //jQuery('.clickable').bind('click', CallPage);
      }
   };

   xhr.onerror = function () {
      display.innerHTML = "<h4>Result from Cross-domain XHR</h4><p>Cross-domain XHR failed</p>";
      display.style.display = "block";
   };
   xhr.open("GET", "http://www.spiegel.de", true);
   xhr.send();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since that you are saying your paragraphs are dynamically generated, then you can add an event listener to the body, and check `event.target`, that is the element where the event had origin.

Here's the code:

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // e.target.id now is the id of the clicked element
    // if you want you can obtain the number in the id and use it like this:

    var page = e.target.id.substr(4);

    // do something
}, false);
```